# c++: How to retrieve Driver installed date programmatically on windows

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, wmi

Is there any way to retrieve driver installed date from wmi or using any API?
I have tried `Win32_pnpsigneddriver`class `InstallDate` property. But for most of the time, it returns null only. Is there any other way to retrieve driver installed date?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have as input ?

Comment: I am trying similar to device manager (devmgmt.msc). I can able to retrieve other properties from `win32_ppsigneddriver` class. But installed date alone always returns null. I want to enumerate all the devices and print its details

Comment: That's where I stuck. I don't know from where to retrieve Driver installed Date

Comment: you can use `CM_Get_Device_ID_ListW` -> `CM_Locate_DevNodeW` -> `CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW` with [`DEVPKEY_Device_InstallDate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-installdate)

Comment: look in `devpkey.h` for properties which you can query

Comment: `DEVPKEY_Device_InstallDate`is of type `DEVPROP_TYPE_FILETIME`. How to convert that to date string

Comment: with `DEVPROP_TYPE_FILETIME` you got `FILETIME` - 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC). you can convert it with [`RtlTimeToTimeFields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-rtltimetotimefields). or `FileTimeToSystemTime`